# I'm using Polkadot js api to fetch the westmint nft pallet collection and their details but i got an error it dosen't show me the instance id

Tags: polkadot-js, polkadot, pallet, nft, statemint

[image]

I tried to figure out the collection id from the api i got an hex value but when i tried to convert that hex to numbers i got an undefined value here is my code
i think the hex value which is outside the json is the number value

```
(async () => {
// Construct
const wsProvider = new WsProvider('wss://westmint-rpc.polkadot.io');
const api = await ApiPromise.create({ provider: wsProvider });

// Do something
  const ADDR = '5DTestUPts3kjeXSTMyerHihn1uwMfLj8vU8sqF7qYrFabHE';
const AccountId32 = '5GCCJthVSwNXRpbeg44gysJUx9vzjdGdfWhioeM7gCg6VyXf';
const u32 = '4';
// Retrieve the last timestamp
const collectionMetadataOf = await api.query.nfts.collectionMetadataOf.entries();
const accounts = api.query.nfts.collectionMetadataOf.entries();
console.log(`${collectionMetadataOf} `);
const obj = JSON.parse(`${collectionMetadataOf} `);
console.log(obj.data)



> Running this code in terminals using node js returns
> node index.js
> return : 
2023-07-13 19:28:26        API/INIT: westmint/9435: Not decorating runtime apis without matching versions: FungiblesApi/2 (1 known)
2023-07-13 19:28:26        API/INIT: westmint/9435: Not decorating unknown runtime apis: 0x8a8047a53a8277ec/1
0xe8d49389c2e23e152fdd6364daadd2cc7c447fa0f5e1581c6e2b96cd7bee295111d2df4e979aa105cf552e9544ebd2b500000000,{"deposit":10087500000,"data":"0x516d584d6452365a75664770533247313248546b6b524b7355766977327238526f4c333472624752643675736742"},0xe8d49389c2e23e152fdd6364daadd2cc7c447fa0f5e1581c6e2b96cd7bee29511c8a02f456942930c9730654ca687a3a04000000,{"deposit":10087500000,"data":"0x516d507955664b50776337475434577978554e414c506f50733563655068364736376974465270737a5753594d38"},0xe8d49389c2e23e152fdd6364daadd2cc7c447fa0f5e1581c6e2b96cd7bee29513436db8bf2d563cb5d2999a82809eded0b000000,{"deposit":10064500000,"data":"0x"},0xe8d49389c2e23e152fdd6364daadd2cc7c447fa0f5e1581c6e2b96cd7bee2951969e061847da7e84337ea78dc577cd1d05000000,{"deposit":10072500000,"data":"0x48656c6c6f20436f6c6c656374696f6e"},0xe8d49389c2e23e152fdd6364daadd2cc7c447fa0f5e1581c6e2b96cd7bee295199850724010e3222888eeb8478c9ffd307000000,{"deposit":10070000000,"data":"0x68656c6c6f20616761696e"},0xe8d49389c2e23e152fdd6364daadd2cc7c447fa0f5e1581c6e2b96cd7bee2951be1f3931028cc05c2e18a319e8f64f9e08000000,{"deposit":10100000000,"data":"0x697066733a2f2f697066732f6261666b7265696236756632716e6833656d6468336634637a3262726778787432786f6c616e62336f796d68753769616a346a616f773734746b6d"},0xe8d49389c2e23e152fdd6364daadd2cc7c447fa0f5e1581c6e2b96cd7bee2951de18007c0afadc771c45bf719bc7fe5103000000,{"deposit":10087500000,"data":"0x516d6357686b664377586a484a434358596d484c4e4452776f6f744d5548384750465356444a6a554b5170513535"},0xe8d49389c2e23e152fdd6364daadd2cc7c447fa0f5e1581c6e2b96cd7bee2951f71f22775221b1945fe6cfa3c6550c7c09000000,{"deposit":10093500000,"data":"0x697066733a2f2f697066732f516d58625172696d4468583277726b76487676764e345852697852313366766d4b5856676b5a354b48325a6f616e"}


`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the same values as you are getting with PolkadotJS UI try this snippet:

```js
const collectionMetadataOf = await api.query.nfts.collectionMetadataOf.entries();
        collectionMetadataOf.forEach(([{ args: [id] }, value]) => {
        const metadata = JSON.parse(`${value}`);
        console.log(id.toHuman());
        console.log(metadata);
});
```

You can see more information and examples of how to parse the information with `entries()` in the docs: [How do I use .entries()/.keys() on double maps?](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/cookbook/storage#how-do-i-use-entrieskeys-on-double-maps)

Comment: thanks bro i appreciate your efforts it solved that issue and you also saved my time amazing i was hopeless when i didn't got any solution but you made my day thanks again

Comment: That's why this site is for, to help devs!